# How to set dynamically height/width of an external image in rdlc report?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

Is it possible to set the width and the height dynamically in an external image used in an rdlc report? And if yes, how?

I want the user to set the width and the height in the settings of my desktop application and with these numbers to display a logo image in the rdlc report.

I found a similar question but no useful answer given.
[How to set height and width for external image in rdlc dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126710/how-to-set-height-and-width-for-external-image-in-rdlc-dynamically)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: work around:
you can write your report dynamically it's XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no way to dynamically set the height and width of an external image used in rdlc report.